# Code in VB work automatically when new data inserted in sheet

Tags: vb.net, excel

I am a beginner, so I hope that my explanation is clear enought. I am trying to find out a way to make my VB code(find last row/find first row) to run automatically when I insert new data in my sheet (I use also the filtering option) and not to be necessary to make it manually(press button play in VB) after I add a new data. I use the next code:

find last row for filtered data

```
Sub LR2()
    Dim lastrow As Long

    lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D3").Value = lastrow
End Sub
```

find first row for filtered data

```
Sub Firstlastrow()

    Dim r As Range
    Dim StartRow As Long
    Dim EndRow As Long

    Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("A6:A9999").Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    ' r is now $A$73351:$A$77343

    StartRow = r.Row ' returns 73351
    EndRow = r.Row + r.Rows.Count - 1

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2").Value = StartRow

End Sub
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Would inserting a button fit your requirements? It would only require one click.

Comment: Inserting a button would be also a good option, but the problem is that I don't now how to do it. do you have any suggestions? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply insert a button. It isn't quite as simple as having it triggered, but it's only one click.

Go to the developer tab in excel. If the developer tab is not there, then go to excel options, customize the ribbon, and click the developer box.

Once in the developer tab, click the arrow under insert and click the one on the top left. That will allow to to put in a button. You can then decide where the button goes, the size, the text on it, and the macro that it will call.

Hopefully this helps!

In regards to your second question:

```
Sub total()

    Call LR2
    Call Firstlastrow

End Sub
```

Have the button call the `total` sub and it'll run both.

Comment: thank you,it is working fine.I still have a problem and maybe you can offer me a solution . What should I do in order to get the first and last row pressing just one button. I don't want to have separate buttons for last row and  first row. I want just one button that will execute both commands(first row and last row). Thank you!

Comment: @Lavi see my updated answer. Please select it as correct if it accomplishes what you intended :)

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not a big fan of using these kind of events (they are expensive since they will run at every single change) You could use the "Worksheet_Change" event.

So for example, this will run the LR2 sub when data in column A:A is changed.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then LR2
End Sub

Sub LR2()
    Dim lastrow As Long

    lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ActiveSheet.Range("D3").Value = lastrow
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your fast replay. I tried the code that you suggested me but when I filter the data the last row does not get update and when I added new data the last row was the same until I pressed again play in VB. Is there a chance that I did not proceed correctly?